# Everything freezes when opening second project in Android Studio 4.1 on Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: linux-mint, android, freeze

This doesn't happen when I open the first project. But it happens after a few minutes, when I close the first project and open another project, or when I open the second project in a new window. Sometimes it logging me out.

Specs:

- System:
  Kernel: 5.9.0-rc4+ x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Cinnamon 4.6.6
  wm: muffin 4.6.2 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 20 Ulyana
  base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
- Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20SM v: Lenovo ThinkBook 15-IIL
  serial:  Chassis: type: 10 v: Lenovo ThinkBook 15-IIL
  serial: 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LVAC/LVAD v: NO DPK serial:  UEFI: LENOVO
  v: DJCN14WW date: 12/11/2019
- Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 47.1 Wh condition: 47.2/45.0 Wh (105%) volts: 12.9/11.4
  model: SMP L19M3PF1 type: Li-poly serial:  status: Unknown
  cycles: 23
- CPU:
  Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-1035G1 bits: 64 type: MT MCP
  arch: Ice Lake rev: 5 L2 cache: 6144 KiB
  flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
  bogomips: 19046
  Speed: 2000 MHz min/max: 400/3600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1996 2: 2000
  3: 1995 4: 2000 5: 1995 6: 2000 7: 1992 8: 2000
- Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0
  chip ID: 8086:8a56
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (ICL GT1) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.4
  direct render: Yes
- Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Smart Sound Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel
  v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:34c8
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.9.0-rc4+
- Network:
  Device-1: Intel Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter
  driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 3000 bus ID: 00:14.3 chip ID: 8086:34f0
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: 
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
  vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 2000 bus ID: 01:00.0
  chip ID: 10ec:8168
  IF: enp1s0 state: down mac: 
  IF-ID-1: docker0 state: down mac: 
  IF-ID-2: tun0 state: unknown speed: 10 Mbps duplex: full mac: N/A
- Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 36.45 GiB (7.8%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: HP model: SSD S700 500GB size: 465.76 GiB
  speed: 6.0 Gb/s serial:  rev: 4A1 scheme: GPT
- Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 451.60 GiB used: 36.45 GiB (8.1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1
- Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 73.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
- Info:
  Processes: 308 Uptime: 23m Memory: 30.89 GiB used: 5.43 GiB (17.6%)
  Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 9.3.0 alt: 9 Shell: bash
  v: 5.0.16 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.38

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upgrading versions of Cinnamon to 4.6.7 and Muffin to 4.6.3 works! No freezes anymore.

Thanks to Mint forum: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1917208#p1917208